# Xamarin Show Keyboard and Focus on an Entry Field

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-softkeyboard

I am using Xamarin.Android and I have a Dialog with Xamarin.Forms.Entry field in it.

How do I show keyboard and give focus to this Entry field when dialog is displayed?

I am using a device, not an emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
dialog.Appearing += (object sender, System.EventArgs e) => yourEntry.Focus ();
```

When you focus to the entry, Keyboard will be shown by default

Here is the sample, i have tried to show keyboard in button click

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="entry" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100" />
    <Button Text="Show" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100" />
</StackLayout>

void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   entry.Focus();
}
```